# Formal definition of the sequence of n-gonal numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than or equal to $3$. I want a formal definition of the sequence of $n$-gonal numbers. For example, when $n = 3$, we get the sequence of triangular numbers, and when $n = 4$, we get the sequence of square numbers, etc. I want a formal, rigorous definition of this concept.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Definitions

Let $S_{n}$ be the sequence of $n$-gonal numbers.
Let $S_{n, k}$ be the $k$th term of the sequence of $n$-gonal numbers.

### Observation

Note the sequences of $n$-gonal numbers for $n = 3, 4, 5$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
   n & S_{n} \\
\hline
   3 & 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ... \\
\hline
   4 & 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... \\
\hline
   5 & 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ... \\
\hline
\end{array}

Observe that

$$S_{n+1, k} - S_{n, k} = S_{3, k-1}$$

Recall that
$$S_{3, k} = \sum_{i = 1}^k i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

It follows that
$$S_{n+1, k} = S_{n, k} + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
$$\implies S_{3 + r, k} = S_{3, k} + r\left(\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\right)$$

Substituting $n = 3 + r$, we get
$$S_{n, k} = S_{3,k} + (n - 3)\left(\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\right) = \frac{(n-2)k^2 - (n-4)k}{2}$$

### Conjecture

$$\forall n \geq 3, n,k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}, S_{n,k} = \frac{(n-2)k^2 - (n-4)k}{2}$$

Can you prove the above result?